# How can I install GCC 4.8 on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, gcc

How can I install GCC 4.8 on Raspberry Pi?  Do I need to compile it from source?  Should I update from Raspbian wheezy to a newer version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your Raspberry Pi is up to date, then you can just download and patch GCC 4.8 to run on you Raspberry Pi.

1. Download GCC sources

   ```
   $ wget ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/unix/languages/gcc/snapshots/LATEST-4.8/*.bz2
   ```
2. Extract sources

   ```
   $ tar xf gcc-4.8-20120826.tar.bz2
   ```
3. Patch sources

   We need to get and apply two debian specific patches for GCC:

   ```
   $ wget http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/gcccvs/branches/sid/gcc-4.7/debian/patches/armhf-triplet.diff?view=co -O armhf-triplet.diff
   $ wget http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/gcccvs/branches/sid/gcc-4.7/debian/patches/gcc-multiarch-trunk.diff?view=co -O gcc-multiarch-trunk.diff
   $ cd gcc-4.8-20120826
   $ patch -p2 -i ../armhf-triplet.diff
   $ patch -p2 -i ../gcc-multiarch-trunk.diff
   ```

   Note: There will be a failed patch in libgcc, don't worry about it, as it's already been applied to gcc-4.8.
4. Recreate `.autoconf` files:

   ```
   $ cd gcc
   $ autoconf2.64
   $ cd ../libjava
   $ autoconf2.64
   $ cd ../
   ```
5. Compile and install GCC: `configure`; `make`; `make install`

Comment: Not configure/make install anymore?

Comment: What does `autoconf2.64` do?

Comment: It appears that the gcc 4.8 snapshot you linked to (step 1) is no longer online. They only seem to keep the last 3 months or so of builds. `wget ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/unix/languages/gcc/snapshots/LATEST-4.8/*.bz2` should do the trick to get their latest build of gcc 4.8. There's also a LATEST-4.9 and LATEST-4.10 folder as well.

Comment: So after step 4, we still have to do the whole `configure; make; make install` commands? Because I'm not seeing any binaries, and `gcc --version` still reports 4.6.

Comment: @Wallacoloo Yes, you do.  I just walked through the process of patching GCC 4.8 so that it could compile properly.

Comment: For step (3) I get: Not Found

Answer (score 8):

In 2015-02-16-raspbian-wheezy is gcc-4.8 already as package (4.8.2), but not default. You can install it apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8 and then change the links in /usr/bin/

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above -- ran into several issues.  This might be easier (I'm trying it now):

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=65516&p=481730

Comment: If you could post the gist of the directions here, that'd be great! It helps prevent link rot if anything ever changes on the linked site.

Comment: The downside to this solution is that it forces you to update you ENTIRE system to Debian Jessie. This may very well cause compatibility issues for some users (myself included).

Comment: In keeping with our [policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/19949), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.

Answer (score 0):

In case any of these options haven't worked for you (or you're running something newer), you can try this. I'm running Raspian with desktop (without included software) on a Raspberry Pi 4.

I went into `/etc/apt/` and modified `sources.list`. The second line in my file says:

```
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

After that, run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, then finally:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
```

***Side note: If you're also wanting to install g++-4.8 (like I was, for tensorflow), you'll need to add these two lines to your `sources.list` file:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

Again, `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, and then:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
```